# How to push a button with javascript loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for a way with javascript to run a code to the console of chrome and push all the buttons with the same CLASS name of a website

the code of the button is this

```
<span><a class="UFILikeLink" href="#" role="button" aria-live="polite" title="Like this" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;>&quot;}" data-reactid=".3k">
  <i class="UFILikeLinkIcon img sp_j2jvp3kCzmm sx_751c68" data-reactid=".3k.0"></i>
  <span data-reactid=".3k.1">Like</span>
</a></span>
```

I have tried this code here

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName('UFILikeLink'); 

for (var i=0;i<el.length; i++) {
    el[i].click();
}
```

Sorry my mistake.

The code is working but if I run the code for the second time it pushes again the button and it's like before.

The thing is that I want to make it like, if the button is pushed once
it will not be pushed again.

Again sorry for the mistake.

If I push the button then the code of the webpage changes to this

```
<span><a class="UFILikeLink UFILinkBright" href="#" role="button" aria-live="polite" title="Unlike this" data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;?&quot;}" data-reactid=".sk">
  <i class="UFILikeLinkIcon img sp_j2jvp3kCzmm sx_c04d59" data-reactid=".sk.0"></i>
  <span data-reactid=".sk.1">Like</span>
</a></span>
```

Comment: any messages on the console?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Is there any error in console?

Comment: @JaromandaX undefined

Comment: Oh sorry my bad its not this the problem sorry i was confused.

Comment: Simple! `$('.UFILikeLink').trigger('click');` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `jquery` tag on your question, so here is how you would do it with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".UFILikeLink").each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });

});
```

This will click on everything that has the class `UFILikeLink` when the page loads.

Comment: i get this error with your code Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library before your own scripts, for example: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: See [this page](http://jquery.com/download/) for different ways of getting jQuery.

Comment: console in chrome refuses to load any library :(

Comment: You have to add the script to your page, use a script tag like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through the selected elements, if you're using jquery.
Simply write this

`$('.UFILikeLink').trigger('click');`

But it seems like you're using pure js. So in that case, you're gonna have to do  something like this.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });

for(var el in els){
    els[el].dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This code works also good as the one that i have in my post. But the problem is that when i execute the code for the second time, it unclicks the items. so all i need is a restriction to say that  if the button is clicked, dont click it again. click only the one that are not clicked.